# Difference between JIRA API and JIRA Align API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

What is JIRA Align API and when to use it? what are the endpoints of JIRA Align Rest API?
Is there any documentation around it ?

Answer (score 1):

*"What is JIRA Align API"* It is the API for Jira Align

*"and when to use it"* Use it whenever you want to

*"what are the endpoints of JIRA Align Rest API?"* They are the things that let you make requests

*"Is there any documentation around it?"*. There certainly is